# How to find documents from date to date in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I would like to return results from DB, from date to date.

```
let resultsArray = await db.collection('scraper-results').find({
                timestamp: {
                    $gte: Date(lastDiff),
                    $lt: Date(new Date())
                }
            }).toArray();
            console.log(resultsArray);
```

I am using this but it returns an empty array, I tried with ISODate as well but I get the error: `ISODate is not defined.`

> lastDiff prints : "2018-10-22T11:10:07.000Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below: (You just need to use `new`)

```
db.getCollection('scraper-results')
.find({
    timestamp: {
        $gte: new Date(lastDiff),
        $lt: new Date()
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
timestamp: {
  $gte: new Date(lastDiff),
  $lt: new Date()
}
```

Observe the difference in output when not using `new` with "2018-10-22T11:10:07.000Z":

```js
console.log(Date('2018-10-22T11:10:07.000Z'));
console.log(new Date('2018-10-22T11:10:07.000Z'));
```

Note that your one is incorrect so it's the equivalent of "now" (today).